# Adding WPF UserControl to Winform project

Tags: wpf, winforms, user-controls

When I try to right click on the project and Add->New Item-> WPF it say to me "No items found".I want to add WPF UserControl to a Winform project. I have this problem only with this project, when I open a new project I can add WPF Usercontrol...I use VS 2010. 10x

Answer (score 0):

see this articls .... it may helps

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745781.aspx

http://keyvan.io/host-wpf-controls-in-windows-forms